# Passing data in Swift between VCs embedded in a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass data forward between two VCs embedded in a Tab Bar Controller. I just want to make the input text fields entries from the first three VCs available in the 4th VC (ResultViewController in attached code image) in order to perform a calculation triggered by an IBAction in the last (4th) view controller. I am pretty new to swift, but have done a lot of research and think that delegates are the way to go....but not sure.  I feel like this should be pretty straight forward. It seems that every video that I have watched about delegates utilize segues,  is this required?  I just want to passed multi user inputs for the first three VCs to the last VC to perform a calculation. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing the view controller one by one?

if  YES, then just have the dictionary variable in the viewcontrollers and pass the values in `prepareForSegue`.

else, have the common variable in Tab Bar VC and collect the values into that variable across the viewcontrollers and then finally use it in 4th VC.

Comment: Thanks Venkat.  I am not pushing them one by one. I just the user to enter data on the first three VCs and go to the last VC (using the nav in the tab bar) and click on an IBAction which performs the calculation that I have set up.

Comment: Venkat,  Could you add some detail on the second method you indicated above....creating a common variable in the TAB Bar VC.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are making this more complicated than you need. Consider making a singleton object which holds the data that all the view controllers can access.  If this is not acceptable, you can get the list of all the top level controllers of the TabBarController like this.

```
func somefunc() {
    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
        if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
            for vc in tabBarViewControllers {
                // do something to the view controller
                // set its delegate or whatever
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ryantxr I really appreciate the input. That has definitely crossed my mind. I will try out your suggestions.  I just needed a little direction.

Comment: ryantxr,  Could you explain the Singleton design process...I have attempt many on that were stated on the internet but have not worked.  I am using Xcode 7.2.1 (swift 2) so I think this is causing me some difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: Make a new class and add your variables to it as class variables.

Comment: Thanks troublemaker:)